# Who can help me:"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;"

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER $$

    CREATE PROCEDURE SP_GET_AUDIO_DETAIL(IN P_ID INT)
    BEGIN   
        SELECT post_content FROM wp_posts WHERE ID= P_ID;
    END $$    
    DELIMITER;
```

> Error: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`$$ DELIMITER`' at line 5".

Comment: Get rid of the word DELIMITER at the end

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is expecting something like `END SOMETHING`, because it's kind of stupid sometimes.

Try:

```
...
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```